# How to get NMecab to output romaji?

Tags: c#, .net, nlp, translation, text-analysis

I'm using [a .NET port of Mecab (called NMecab)](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/nmecab/) to try to parse Japanese Hiragana, Katakana, and Kanji to romaji.

Here's my code:

```
using NMeCab;    
MeCabTagger _tagger;

public string Parse(string input)
{
    _tagger = MeCabTagger.Create();
    _tagger.OutPutFormatType = "lattice";
    _tagger.LatticeLevel = MeCabLatticeLevel.Two;


    var output = _tagger.Parse(input);

    return output;
}
```

When I call `Parse(input)` using the following Japanese text: "ども"

I get the output: "ども助詞,接続助詞,*,*,*,*,ども,ドモ,ドモ EOS"

I'm looking for the romaji of "ども", which would be "domo."

I've tried to use Mecab directly as [discussed in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365931/trying-to-get-libmecab-dll-mecab-to-work-with-c-sharp), but get the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge none of the dictionaries used by MeCab (IPA, Jumandic, or Unidic) includes romaji transcription of words. And actually there is no need for that:

1. There exist different transcription schemes (e.g. Hepburn, kunrei, 99 siki);
2. Information on the pronunciation of lexical units is already available (e.g. ドモ).

You have to write your own transcription routine... or look for an existing katakana-romaji transcription module (compatible with your transcription scheme)...

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks... thought MeCab handled the romaji translation. Instead it looks like it simply converts kanji down to hiragana/katakana. Then I just roll my own hiragana/katakana conversion.

Comment: Actually the hiragana/katakana transcription is part of the dictionary... you can have a look at the IPA dictionary source files (*.csv).